# How to compare SQL time column to time now?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a column with `time` type and the entries are saved as `12:15:00`, what I'd like to do is get

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE time > NOW()` however this doesn't work because `NOW()` returns a `datetime` not just time. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: create a datetime value with the current date and your time value.

Comment: @DanBracuk that's not an option, I can't change that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `time()` function or [`curtime()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curtime):

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE time > curtime();
```